# H2 UI is connected but not able logged in while using webflux and reactive H2 Database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, h2

I am working on some reactive application using webflux and H2 Reactive H2 Database. H2 console UI able to view but not able to connect inside of it its showing not suitable driver.

[image]

Is anyone having any idea How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use only JDBC URLs in H2 Console, so URL should be `jdbc:h2:mem:reactive-app` or something like it.

Since release of Java 21 with Project Loom asynchronous APIs aren't very useful. Oracle stopped development of ADBA in 2019 in favor of fiber-ready JDBC drivers. Its competitor R2DBC also isn't under active development these days and usage of R2DBC doesn't look like a good idea.